# Propiedades de objetos en JavaScript

Tags: javascript, objeto

Tengo un objeto que inicialmente tiene una sola propiedad:

```
const obj = {
  algo: ...
}
```

yo quiero agregarle mas propiedades , las cuales sus `keys` sean numeros, por ejemplo:

```
const obj = {
  algo: ...,
  1: ...,
  2: ...,
  3: ...,
  ...
}
```

La cantidad de propiedades depende de una variable, la cual recibiria por parametro. Supongamos que recibo una variable que tiene el valor `3`, yo quisiera que el output final sea:

```
const obj = {
  algo: ...,
  1: ...,
  2: ...,
  3: ...
}
```

pero no me queda de esa forma, sino, de la siguiente:

```
const obj = {
  1: ...,
  2: ...,
  3: ...,
  algo: ...,
}
```

se me aplica como un orden, hay alguna forma que me permita que la propieda `algo`, quede al principio?

Comment: ........ ¿Que hiciste para rellenar el array?, realmente no podemos decirte que esta mal en tu código porque no aportarte el código que usaste para rellenar el array y también ¿Usaste php para rellenar el array?

Comment: No creo que esto sea posible (hay manera, pero imposible empezando por el objeto que muestras) ya que los objetos no tienen un orden. Prueba con matrices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El orden de los objetos viene determinado por el siguiente algoritmo, y en este mismo orden:

1. Primero los Key's tipo índice de matriz, es decir enteros positivos
2. Segundo Keys's de tipo string por orden de inserción
3. Por último Key's tipo [Simbolo](https://javascript.info/symbol) por orden de inserción

Fuente: https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-ordinaryownpropertykeys

Lo que podrías hacer es agregar un prefijo para obligar a que sea string

```js
const obj = {
  algo: ""
}

for(let i=1; i<=3; i++){
  obj[`#${i}`] = "valor " + i;
}

console.log(obj);
```

Por otro lado, la única situación que se me viene a la mente para necesitar el orden en un objeto es que necesites un Diccionario ordenado por inserción. Para esto puede ocupar la clase [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)

Donde dice:

> El objeto Map contiene pares clave-valor y **recuerda la inserción
> original Orden de las llaves**

Que es exactamente lo que tú quieres

Ejemplo:

```js
const map = new Map();

map.set("algo", 0);
map.set(1, 1);
map.set(2, 3);
map.set(3, 3);


for(let item of map){
  console.log(item);
}
```

Comment: ... pensé que el usuario había usado php, como su array es constante

Comment: mmm En las etiquetas dice Javascript

Comment: No, el usuario no ha dicho si es php, solo lo pensé porque si quiere llenar un array constante usando una variable que también sea afectado el código la opción que me imagino sería usar php

Comment: Si pruebas con las claves `1: ...,` no funciona.

Comment: Hola @Cris223511.dev, que es lo que no funciona ?? no entendí

Comment: En el caso del primer ejemplo, si existen claves que son 1 2 y 3 y están debajo de la clave `algo`, esos valores irán primero y luego el `algo`, y esto es lo que justo el OP preguntaba, de que `algo` vaya primero y no al último cuando existen las claves 1 2 y 3 (tal cual como su ejemplo)...

Comment: @Cris223511.dev no entiendo, en ambos ejemplos `Algo` queda primero.  Yo le que le estoy diciendo es que le agregue un prefijo como por ejemplo un `#`, de esta manera se mantiene el orden, y es una lógica parecida a cuando se ocupa document.querySelector("#id"), donde uno tiene agregar aquel prefijo

Comment: Claro, funciona de esa forma, solo menciono que si inicias con el objeto que menciona el OP (con las claves 1 2 3), el orden cambia.

Comment: @DanielBriceño, no se menciona la palabra `Array` por ninguna parte en la pregunta. Y las etiquetas de la pregunta son: `javascript` y `objeto`.